# How to or can I start up virtual host on vmware esxi directly, not from vsphere client?

Tags: vmware, esxi

Now, I have installed a desktop operating system(as Windows 8.1) on vmware esxi, can I start up it directly on vmware esxi, not from vsphere client? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, You can start up your VM via ESXi directly.

First, You must access ssh to ESXi host.

And You start up your VM as VM-cli.

refer to VM cli document in VMware.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the VM directly from the ESXi host by connecting SSH to it. From the SSH terminal, use the command **vim-cmd**

See the command below

**vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms or vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms |grep**

After you get the VM-id, power it up using this command

**vim-cmd vmsvc/power.getstate**

For more information, refer to this [link](http://nigelhickey.com/power-vm-via-ssh/)

Note: you will have to enable SSH from the ESXi host console, refer to this [link](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=8375637)